React query showing data for a different endpoint and not for the endpoint desired
I am building an application which fetches data from different sports and render the data, I am using react query and axios. I was trying to refactor my code by using one function to fetch the API for different sports, since the URL for the sports are almost alike.
Here is my function which sets the URL,
const getBaseURL = (sport: Sports) => {
  switch (sport) {
    case "basketball":
    case "baseball":
    case "rugby":
    case "hockey":
      return `https://v1.${sport}.api-sports.io`;
    case "football":
      return `https://v3.football.api-sports.io`;
    default:
      return "";
  }
};

const getHost = (sport: Sports) => {
  switch (sport) {
    case "basketball":
    case "baseball":
    case "rugby":
    case "hockey":
      return `v1.${sport}.api-sports.io`;
    case "football":
      return `v3.football.api-sports.io`;
    default:
      return "";
  }
};

function createAxiosInstance(baseURL: string, headers: Record<string, string>) {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    headers: headers,
  });
}

export const getFixturesByDate = async (date: string, sport: Sports) => {
  const baseURL = getBaseURL(sport);
  const headers = {
    "x-rapidapi-host": getHost(sport),
    "x-rapidapi-key":
      process.env.RAPIDAPI_KEY ?? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RAPIDAPI_KEY!,
  };
  const axiosInstance = createAxiosInstance(baseURL, headers);

  switch (sport) {
    case "basketball":
      return (
        await axiosInstance.get<APIResponse<Games<BasketballScores>>>(
          `/games?date=${date}`
        )
      ).data.response;
    case "baseball":
      return (
        await axiosInstance.get<APIResponse<Games<BaseballScores>>>(
          `/games?date=${date}`
        )
      ).data.response;
    case "rugby":
      return (
        await axiosInstance.get<APIResponse<GamesWithPeriods<number | null>>>(
          `/games?date=${date}`
        )
      ).data.response;
    case "hockey":
      return (
        await axiosInstance.get<
          APIResponse<GamesWithPeriodsAndEvents<number | null>>
        >(`/games?date=${date}`)
      ).data.response;
    case "football":
      return (
        await axiosInstance.get<APIResponse<Fixtures>>(`/fixtures?date=${date}`)
      ).data.response;
    default:
      return undefined;
  }
};


And this is my react query function
export function useFixturesByDate(date: string, sport: Sports) {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: [sport, "fixtures", date],
    queryFn: () => getFixturesByDate(date, sport),
    staleTime: 5 * 60 * 1000,
    enabled: !!date || !!sport,
  });
}

Here is the HomeFixtures component which is calling the useQuery hook,

const HomeFixtures = ({ sport }: Props) => {
  const { status } = useStatusStore();
  const { date } = useDateStore();
  const { league } = useLeagueStore();
  const formattedDate = format(date, "yyyy-MM-dd");

  const { data, isFetching, isError, error } = useFixturesByDate(
    formattedDate,
    sport
  );

//rest of the code

And here is the parent container, calling the HomeFixtures in which I am passing the different sports. I am using Next JS app router, so each page is having a different sport.
Basketball
      <div className="h-[calc(100vh-150px)] overflow-y-auto px-6">
        <HomeFixtures sport={"basketball"} />
      </div>

Baseball
      <div className="h-[calc(100vh-150px)] overflow-y-auto px-6">
        <HomeFixtures sport={"baseball"} />
      </div>

As you can see that when a different sport is passed to the hook, it will call the query, and it does call the hook. But when I try to inspect the query devtools, I see that the data for 'basketball' is present even if I am trying to fetch the data for 'baseball' or any other sport, and only when I click on refetch in the devtools, I'd get a new set of data.
Now, I have no clue why this is happening, please help me figure this out.
Note: Previously I was trying to prefetch the query, and then wrap in the component in a HydrationBoundary, and access it, since I wanted to fetch the data in the server. I am putting a halt to this, I just want to figure out what I am doing wrong, that is making my application behave the way it is behaving.

So, I kind of figured out what was causing the error, I have a FilterWrapper component in the parent container, in which I want the data too, so I am calling the useQuery hook there too with the same endpoint, when I remove that query from there, my application works, just the way I want.
I can prefetch the query, and pass the data to the component, but the problem with this method is I would want to fetch the query everytime the date changes, which I cannot figure out how to achieve with this. Any ideas?

You'll have to show us how the FilterWrapper is working for us to know what's wrong with it. Update your question with those details.
